# jQuery Not allowing Second Click on Mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to run a click function after opening a menu in wordpress. My current set up is the following.

I am trying something along the likes of [this](http://codepen.io/ishio/pen/Kwvapv) Sorry, it's hard to post over wordpress content.

```
jQuery(function () {
    var mqm = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width:767px)');
    if (mqm.matches){
      jQuery("header .menu .menu-item-has-children").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery(this).find("a span").toggleClass('open');
      jQuery(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
    });
   }
});
```

I'm able to get it to open and close on mobile, however the second click on the parent it just closes it.

Comment: can oyu show the html?

Comment: Off topic: If you pass the dollar as an argument like so you can use it in your function instead of 'jQuery': `jQuery(function ($) {`

Comment: In the post is the codepen.io http://codepen.io/ishio/pen/Kwvapv

Comment: I am using jQuery due to it being wordpress in my js file. I just adjusted it for the codepen to display